# ¿Cómo filtro los datos un dataframe en otro dataframe?

Tags: r, datatable, r-dplyr

Tengo dos dataframe como los siguientes (simplificados):

Dataframe_1

```
| id | type |
|----|------|
| a  | 1    |
| a  | 2    |
| b  | 2    |
| c  | 3    |
| d  | 1    |
| a  | 4    |
```

Dataframe_2

```
|  id  |
|------|
|  a   |
|  b   |
```

Necesito eliminar del Dataframe_1 todos los elementos del Dataframe_2 de manera que el resultado sea:

Dataframe_3

```
| id | type |
|----|------|
| c  | 3    |
| d  | 1    |
```

Normalmente utilizo

```
library(dplyr)
filter(id==a)
```

Sin embargo el Dataframe_2 es una lista muy larga y no puedo incluir todos los valores en el código.

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2):

Con la grámatica de `dplyr` lo que buscas se conoce como un [`anti_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html), es decir las filas de una tabla que no coincidan con otra:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(id = c('a','a','b','c','d','a'), type=c(1,2,2,3,1,4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(id = c('a', 'b'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

anti_join(df1, df2, by="id")

  id type
1  c    3
2  d    1
```

Es necesario indicar el parámetro `by` para establecer la columna por la que buscaremos las coincidencias, ya que sino, por defecto el `anti_join` buscaría usando todas las columnas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Funciona perfectamente.